# Meteor 0.8 and Jade

Tags: meteor, meteorite

I'm trying to upgrade my application to Meteor 0.8 which uses the new Blaze templating engine.

```
$ meteor update
my-app: updated to Meteor 0.8.0.

$ mrt update
```

The thing is that I'm using Jade and after running meteor, it prompted:

```
While building the application:
<runJavaScript-38>:167:38: Object #<Object> has no method 'compile' (compiling modules/homepage/client/views/_homepage.jade)
  at Object.html_scanner._handleTag (<runJavaScript-38>:167:38)
  at Object.html_scanner.scan (<runJavaScript-38>:118:20)
  at handler (<runJavaScript-38>:526:30)
```

I've seen in [the new blog post](https://www.meteor.com/blog/2014/03/27/meteor-080-introducing-blaze) that I needed to add jade with meteorite.

```
mrt add jade
```

But now, by running Meteor, the following error appears:

```
=> Started proxy.
=> Started MongoDB.     
=> Starting your app...
/Users/mac/.meteor/tools/c2a0453c51/lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:173
                    throw(ex);
                          ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
  at /Users/mac/.meteor/tools/c2a0453c51/tools/packages.js:750:28
  at Function._.each._.forEach (/Users/mac/.meteor/tools/c2a0453c51/lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:87:22)
  at /Users/mac/.meteor/tools/c2a0453c51/tools/packages.js:745:9
  at Array.forEach (native)
  at Function._.each._.forEach (/Users/mac/.meteor/tools/c2a0453c51/lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
  at [object Object]._.extend._allHandlers (/Users/mac/.meteor/tools/c2a0453c51/tools/packages.js:744:7)
  at [object Object]._.extend.registeredExtensions (/Users/mac/.meteor/tools/c2a0453c51/tools/packages.js:768:24)
  at [object Object].slice.getSourcesFunc (/Users/mac/.meteor/tools/c2a0453c51/tools/packages.js:1713:41)
  at [object Object]._.extend.build (/Users/mac/.meteor/tools/c2a0453c51/tools/packages.js:279:17)
  at /Users/mac/.meteor/tools/c2a0453c51/tools/packages.js:1088:13
  at Array.forEach (native)
  at Function._.each._.forEach (/Users/mac/.meteor/tools/c2a0453c51/lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
  at [object Object]._.extend.build (/Users/mac/.meteor/tools/c2a0453c51/tools/packages.js:1087:7)
  at [object Object]._.extend.getForApp (/Users/mac/.meteor/tools/c2a0453c51/tools/library.js:285:9)
  at /Users/mac/.meteor/tools/c2a0453c51/tools/bundler.js:1762:25
  at Object.capture (/Users/mac/.meteor/tools/c2a0453c51/tools/buildmessage.js:191:5)
  at Object.exports.bundle (/Users/mac/.meteor/tools/c2a0453c51/tools/bundler.js:1697:31)
  at [object Object]._.extend._runOnce (/Users/mac/.meteor/tools/c2a0453c51/tools/run-app.js:396:32)
  at [object Object]._.extend._fiber (/Users/mac/.meteor/tools/c2a0453c51/tools/run-app.js:520:28)
  at /Users/mac/.meteor/tools/c2a0453c51/tools/run-app.js:340:12
```

I do not see where the error comes from.

Comment: Using the new jade package works for me when I start with an empty project. How were you compiling your jade files prior to 0.8?

Comment: In .meteor/packages.js, I just had the following packages: standard-app-packages, coffeescript, accounts-base, accounts-password, iron-router, belt-jade-handlebars, email, handlebar-helpers and npm. This worked, but I didn't add the jade package.

Comment: Interesting. So what happens when you `mrt remove belt-jade-handlebars`?

Comment: Did you update iron-router? Older versions don't work with Blaze.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the problem is coming from the [belt-jade-handlebars](https://github.com/SimonDegraeve/meteor-jade-handlebars) package. I don't really know what is happening but I guess that it is not up to date with the new Blaze engine. Just remove it if you can.

```
mrt remove belt-jade-handlebars.
```